# A question on how to change the qed-symbol of amsthm

Tags: symbols, amsthm

I am using the `amsthm` package and get a blank square like `$\Square$` at the end of proofs. How can I redefine to get the black Halmos tombstone `$\Blacksquare$` instead?

I want the symbol to be right aligned, but it would be useful if I were to be able to switch off the right-alignment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Redefine `\qedsymbol`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
A test text
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wouldn't recommend to switch off right alignment for the end-mark (it's not standard, so readers might miss the end-mark and quite franckly, it looks ugly), but you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \nolinebreak\qedsymbol\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
A test text some more text and some more text and some more text and
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **barbara beeton** mentions in [`her comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256944/a-question-on-how-to-change-the-qed-symbol-of-amsthm/256945?noredirect=1#comment615765_256945), it might be desired to turn off right alignment on a per-case basis; in this case, it's enough to locally redefine `\qedsymbol` to be empty and then add the desired symbol at the end (taking some care to prevent undesired line breaks); something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
\newcommand\placeqed{\nobreak\enspace$\blacksquare$}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
A test text some more text and some more text and some more text and
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{}
A test text some more text and some more text and some more text and\placeqed
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is nice! Do you know how i may turn off the rught alignment?

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal I updated my answer with a better redefinition. However, I insist, I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: to get rid of the automatic right-aligned symbol, it's sufficient to `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}`.  then the desired symbol can simply be inserted at the end of the text with `\nobreak\hspace{<dimen>}\<symbolname>`; i specified `\nobreak` because such a symbol is likely to get overlooked on a line by itself (and it doesn't look very good either).  the redefinition of the symbol will persist only for the current proof; this enables both formats to be used, while redefining `proof` limits your options.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, it's better to have both options. I'll add your suggestion to my answer. Thanks.