# Modify \qed to have an empty box offset to the top left

Tags: symbols, amsthm

in the MWE below, how do you go about getting the `\qed` box to show up like:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\qed
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\raisebox{2pt}{$\square$}\,\llap{$\blacksquare$}}
```

in your preamble.

---

See [A question on how to change the qed-symbol of amsthm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256944/a-question-on-how-to-change-the-qed-symbol-of-amsthm) for more on changing the qed-symbol.

The command above builds the new qed symbol out of the `\square` and `\blacksquare` symbols from `amssymb`, by vertically shifting the `\square` up a tiny bit (`\raisebox`) and printing the `\blacksquare` on top of it (`\llap`). The horizontal offset is achieved with a small space `\,`.

Comment: I usually warn about `\llap` in LaTeX. Here there is no issue, because the mode is certainly horizontal, but in other cases it may have surprising effects. Better doing `\makebox[0pt][r]{...}` instead of `\llap{...}`

Comment: For those interested in what egreg just wrote: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146098/llap-or-rlap-at-the-beginning-of-an-indented-paragraph is an example where the effect can be unexpected for those not "in the know".