# Changing qed for separate proofs

Tags: symbols, proof-package

I am using Latex, and I can't share my specific code for privacy reasons, but I want to remove the qed symbol for separate proofs, but not change every proof in the document. The only thing is don't know how to do that, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: well you will have to share code if you want help.

Comment: This is not mathoverflow, you can make up fake theorems and proofs.

Comment: Welcome to `TeX.SE` ... Without seeing your code, not able to give correct solution, atleast generate your code with using standard inputs like `book.cls`

Comment: Sorry, but I can't put in my code, but I am looking to see if there is some command you can put in with the proof code so that you can change the qed for only that proof.

Comment: You don't have to put here your real code but at least the document class and the loaded packages. It might be as simple as `\renewcommand{\qed}{}` _within_ the `proof` environment but without code it's only a guess.

Comment: If you are using `amsthm`, you can locally redfine `\qedsymbol` within the proof.  This question provides some additional information: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/256944

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ntheorem` package allows you to redefine QED symbols that way.  See section 2.6 of [the manual,](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/ntheorem.pdf) and the examples in section 4.